# Can I download Office Starter 2010 legally?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, download

Office 2010 is Microsoft's ad-supported version of Office, which is bundled & pre-installed with OEM. Recently, I wiped my hard disk off the OEM bloatware stuff and installed Windows 7 Ultimate from my licensed copy that I had purchased.

I wish to install Office 2010. Can I download it from MSFT's site? Is it available for download? My word processing and spreadsheet needs are very light, so I don't need the Standard and Pro versions. Please don't suggest OpenOffice/Libre Office.

Comment: If you had your install still, you can make a version of the two bits of software that are in office, that run off a USB drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/products/office/pages/office_2010_starter.aspx explains the answer, in short, "no".

> **How Is Office Starter 2010 Offered?**
>
> Office Starter 2010 is not a trial–it
>   has a perpetual license that does not
>   expire. Office Starter 2010 is an
>   advertising-supported base
>   productivity suite that is available
>   only on new PCs. It must be preloaded
>   on new PCs at the point of
>   manufacture. **Office Starter 2010 is
>   not available for existing PCs at any
>   time after manufacture**; for example,
>   Office Starter 2010 cannot be
>   installed on new PCs being sold by
>   resellers, even brand-new PCs. It will
>   not be sold through distribution or
>   available to end users as a standalone
>   product.
>
> To learn more about how to purchase
>   and distribute Office Starter 2010
>   licenses, visit the worldwide OPC
>   Office 2010 Licensing page.

*my emphasis added mid-paragraph*

Comment: well that sucks. Plan B, then perhaps. Thanks. I'll upvote when UTC day rolls over, I'm currently out of upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Home and Student](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/home-and-student/) version? Can be installed on up to 3 computers as well, so you can sort of divide the price by 3 :)

See [Office 2010: Which suite is right for you?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2010-which-suite-is-right-for-you-FX101825640.aspx)